# focusing on a control before saving

Tags: c#, uwp

So we have an app and we are using an auto suggest box where the user starts tying in the word until they select the word they want.  Once they click on that word, it goes to a text box.

I find that when I select the word and click my save button, it doesnt save my selection.  It only saves my selection if i click inside the textbox before I hit save.  I want to avoid having the user having to clikc in the textbox before saving so I want to ad focus to the textbox.  Is there an easy one liner that will accomplish this?

This is the method below that populates the textbox after selecting the word:

'''

```
private void StructureAutoSuggest_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null && args.ChosenSuggestion.ToString() != "No results found" && sender.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                strucType.Text = args.ChosenSuggestion.ToString();
                strucType.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                //Reset litho box
                strucType.Text = string.Empty;
            }

            //Update list that are bound to lithology selection
            strucViewModel.InitFill2ndRound(strucType.Text);

        }
```

'''

'''

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="StructureAutoSuggest" x:Uid="StructureAutoSuggest"
                                                RelativePanel.RightOf="structTypeSearch"
                                                RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="structTypeSearch"
                                                TextChanged="StructureAutoSuggest_TextChanged"
                                                QuerySubmitted="StructureAutoSuggest_QuerySubmitted"
                                                Width="300"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="strucType" Header="" x:Uid="StructDialogType" 
                                 RelativePanel.Below="StructureAutoSuggest" RelativePanel.RightOf="structTypeSearch"
                                 Width="Auto" Style="{ThemeResource TextboxMandatoryField}" IsReadOnly="True" FontWeight="Bold"
                                 Text ="{x:Bind strucViewModel.StructClassTypeDetail, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 TextChanging="StrucType_TextChanging" />
```

'''

Comment: Could you mind share your xaml code, and what's the strucType control ?

Comment: Sure.  strucType is a textbox that stores the value selected from by autosuggestbox.

Comment: Ok, during the testing, it works in my side if we call  `strucType.Text = args.ChosenSuggestion.ToString();` in `QuerySubmitted` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `AutoSuggestBox`'s `QuerySubmitted` event:

```
StructureAutoSuggest.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

It's likely that there's an issue elsewhere though, like Nico Zhu has suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460742/focusing-on-a-control-before-saving#comment121021645_68460742).